# How do I assign the boolean value returned by ansible.builtin.search to a variable in Ansible?

Tags: regex, ansible

I'm trying to use `ansible.builtin.search` to assign the boolean result to a variable and print it out using debug.

I tried using code from Examples from [Ansible Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/search_test.html#examples), but I don't see the expected result. Instead of the boolean result, I see the entire search string in the debug output.

Here is my code:

```yaml
---
- name: test search
  hosts: linux
  remote_user: xxx
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes

  vars:
    url: "https://example.com/users/foo/resources/bar"
    foundmatch: url is ansible.builtin.search("users")

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{foundmatch}}"  # expect this to print the boolean value 

    - debug:
        msg: "matched pattern 3"
      when: url is ansible.builtin.search("users")

    - debug:
        msg: "matched pattern 4"
      when: url is search("XXXusers")
```

The comparison logic in "when:" is working as expected.
But the {{ foundmatch }} is being printed by debug as :
"msg": "url is ansible.builtin.search("users")"
instead of a boolean value.

What am I missing ?
Am I reading the documentation wrong and search can only be used for comparison and not assignment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your variable assignment to use the `"{{ expression }}"` syntax. Note that the search term 'users' is now within single quotes as a result of the change.

```
vars:
  foundmatch: "{{ url is ansible.builtin.search('users') }}"
```

Without the curly brace, Ansible doesn't know to evaluate that as a Jinja2 expression, and instead assumes that it is a string.

The reason that it works as expected for you in your `when` conditions is because

> The when clause is a raw Jinja2 expression without double curly braces.
> ([Documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#basic-conditionals-with-when))